# Run an Angular 4 Script via a scheduled CRON

Tags: javascript, linux, angular, cron

We have an APP we built in Angular for Android phones. Part of the logic has become very complex, and we would like to move it to our server and run it every hours as a CRON instead of in the Phone APP. I have searched and keep finding how to schedule CRON's via Angular, but not how to run an Angular file via a Linux CRON. Don't need help with CRON's, but don't fully understand Angular and how to execute via the command line...

Comment: This sounds a bit like you're merging data-generation with UI details...it doesn't make sense (to me) why you would want to generate static UI for a framework like angular.  Without knowing more, it seems like you should be able to do all of the math/logic on the server to generate a static data set (like a .json file) which you could load into your UI for Angular to display.

Comment: Should have asked a simple question, how can I execute an Angular file from a linux command line

Comment: Angular is not a language. Angular is a framework for building UI. I think that you want to execute your Angular app's logic in the command-line, so actually you want to execute javascript files in the command line. Get the app's file you want to execute and use node for it. But be aware that you may have to adapt the code because it won't run as a browser application supported by the Angular framework and all of it's features.

Answer (score 0):

OK thanks the comments are helpful. So the answer is I need to be able to run something called NODE.JS which has a command line interface. In researching there is a serve install, then I can execute java script files via the command line.

UPDATE: Installed NODE.JS and now can run the Angular code via the command line, very good.

Comment: For *this* you can get lots of examples by googling `node web scraping` (although I haven't used it, yet, `http://www.horsemanjs.org/` looks like it's easy to use)